# Winsock2 & JNA, can't get WSAEnumProtocols() to work properly

Tags: java, jna, winsock2

*(perhaps I explained the problem with an annoying level of detail, the tl;dr version is in the bottom)*

I've been trying to use JNA to create a simple Winsock test application in Java. The first function I called was WSAStartup(), using the following code:

```
public interface Ws2_32 extends Library {
    Ws2_32 INSTANCE = (Ws2_32) Native.loadLibrary("ws2_32", Ws2_32.class);

    int WSAStartup(short version, LPWSADATA lpwsaData);

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    LPWSADATA   lpwsaData = new LPWSADATA();
    short       version = 2;
    int         result = Ws2_32.INSTANCE.WSAStartup(version,lpwsaData);

    System.out.println("WSAStartup() returned: " + result);

    if((resultado = Ws2_32.INSTANCE.WSAStartup(version,lpwsaData)) == 0){
        System.out.println("LPWSADATA struct:");
        System.out.println("wVersion: " + lpwsaData.wVersion);
        System.out.println("wHighVersion: " + lpwsaData.wHighVersion);

        System.out.print("szDescription: ");
        for(byte b : lpwsaData.szDescription){
            System.out.print((char) b);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");

        System.out.print("szSystemStatus: ");
        for(byte b : lpwsaData.szSystemStatus){
            System.out.print((char) b);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");

        System.out.println("iMaxSockets: " + lpwsaData.iMaxSockets);
        System.out.println("iMaxUdpDg: " + lpwsaData.iMaxUdpDg");
    }
}
```

This works, and I get the following values:

> wVersion: 2
>
> wHighVersion: 514
>
> szDescription: WinSock 2.0
>
> szSystemStatus: Running
>
> iMaxSockets: 0
>
> iMaxUdpDg: 0

After the succesful return of WSAStartup() I tried to call WSAEnumProtocols() but I got the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'WSAEnumProtocols': The specified procedure could not be found.

Then I opened ws2_32.dll using Dependency Walker and I found that there was no function with that name. I only found 3 with a similar name: WSAEnumProtocolsA(), WSAEnumProtocolsW() and WSCEnumProtocols().
I'm going to use WSAEnumProtocolsA() as an example, but I used the next procedure with all 3 of them and got the same results:

First I called WSAStartup() and no error was returned.
According to the MSDN definition of WSAEnumProtocols, the first call to the function should be something like this:
    WSAEnumProtocols(null, wsaprotocol_info, lpdwBufferLength)
The first parameter is null, the second is a pointer to a WSAPROTOCOL_INFO struct and the third is the length of the buffer. If that length is zero, then the function should return -1 (SOCKET_ERROR) and a call to WSAGetLastError() should return WSAENOBUFS, meaning that the buffer is not big enough to contain the info returned by WSAEnumProtocols() and should set the variable lpdwBufferLength with the minimum buffer size that can be passed to WSAEnumProtocols to retrieve all the requested information.
I can't get this to work. WSAEnumProtocols() returns -1 but the value of lpdwBufferLength is not changed and WSAGetLastError() returns 0 instead of 10055 (WSAENOBUFS)

I also tried to use WSASetLastError() and set it to some other error code and then calling WSAGetLastError(), but it always returned 0.

**tl;dr** 
I can't get WSAEnumProtocols(null, wsaprotocol_info, lpdwBufferLength) to work. WSAEnumProtocols() returns -1 but the value of lpdwBufferLength is not changed and WSAGetLastError() returns 0 instead of 10055 (WSAENOBUFS)

**UPDATE:**

This is the interface I'm using to declare the Winsock functions

```
public interface Ws2_32 extends Library {
    Ws2_32 INSTANCE = (Ws2_32) Native.loadLibrary("ws2_32", Ws2_32.class);

    int WSAStartup(short version, LPWSADATA lpwsaData);
    int WSAEnumProtocolsW(int[] lpiProtocols, WSAPROTOCOL_INFO lpProtocolBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);
    int WSACleanup();
    int WSAGetLastError();
    int WSASetLastError(int iError);
}
```

This is the code from where I'm calling the functions:

```
public class TestWSAEnumProtocolsA {

    public void start(){

        WSAPROTOCOL_INFO        wsaprotocol_info = new WSAPROTOCOL_INFO();
        LPWSADATA               lpwsaData = new LPWSADATA();
        int                     lpdwBufferLength = -2;
        int                     result = 0;
        short                   version = 514;

        if((result = Ws2_32.INSTANCE.WSAStartup(version, lpwsaData)) != 0){
            System.out.println("Error #" + result + " at WSAStartup()");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("WSAStartup() finished correctly.");

            if((result = Ws2_32.INSTANCE.WSAEnumProtocols(null, wsaprotocol_info, lpdwBufferLength)) == -1){
                System.out.println("WSAEnumProtocolsW() returned: " + result);
                System.out.println("lpdwBufferLength is: " + lpdwBufferLength);

                System.out.println("WSAGetLastError() returned: " + Ws2_32.INSTANCE.WSAGetLastError());

                System.out.println("Now I'm setting it to 10004");
                Ws2_32.INSTANCE.WSASetLastError(10004);
                System.out.println("WSAGetLastError() returned: " + Ws2_32.INSTANCE.WSAGetLastError());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That code produced the following output:

> WSAStartup() finished correctly.
>
> WSAEnumProtocolsW() returned: -1
>
> lpdwBufferLength is: -2
>
> WSAGetLastError() returned: 0
>
> Now I'm setting it to 10004
>
> WSAGetLastError() returned: 0

This is how I've defined the structures I use when calling those functions:

```
public class WinSock2_structs {

    public static class LPWSADATA extends Structure{

        public short            wVersion;
        public short            wHighVersion;
        public byte             szDescription[] = new byte[256+1];
        public byte             szSystemStatus[] = new byte[128+1];
        public short            iMaxSockets;
        public short            iMaxUdpDg;
        public char             lpVendorInfo;       
}

    public static class WSAPROTOCOLCHAIN extends Structure{

        public int   ChainLen;
        public int   ChainEntries[] = new int[7];
    }

    public static class GUID extends Structure{

        public int      Data1;
        public short    Data2;
        public short    Data3;
        public short    Data4;
        public byte     Data5[] = new byte[8];

    }

    public static class WSAPROTOCOL_INFO extends Structure{

        public int                  dwServiceFlags1;
        public int                  dwServiceFlags2;
        public int                  dwServiceFlags3;
        public int                  dwServiceFlags4;
        public int                  dwProviderFlags;
        public GUID                 ProviderId;
        public int                  dwCatalogEntryId;
        public WSAPROTOCOLCHAIN     ProtocolChain;
        public int                  iVersion;
        public int                  iAddressFamily;
        public int                  iMaxSockAddr;
        public int                  iMinSockAddr;
        public int                  iSocketType;
        public int                  iProtocol;
        public int                  iProtocolMaxOffset;
        public int                  iNetworkByteOrder;
        public int                  iSecurityScheme;
        public int                  dwMessageSize;
        public int                  dwProviderReserved;
        public char                 szProtocol[] = new char[256];

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code that is trying to use `WSAEnumProtocols()` and `WSAGetLastError()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `WSAStartup()` twice, which will require you to call `WSACleanup()` twice to unload WinSock correctly.  You should only be calling `WSAStartup()` once.

The `szProtocol` member of the `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` structure is an array of `TCHAR` elements.  `TCHAR` maps to `char` or `wchar_t` depending on whether the calling app is compiled for ANSI/MBCS or UNICODE.  That is why there is no `WSAEnumProtocols()` function in ws2_32.dll.  There are separate `WSAEnumProtocolsA()` (for Ansi) and `WSAEnumProtocolsW()` (for Unicode) functions instead.  Since Java uses Unicode strings, you should have your JNA code use `WSAEnumProtocolsW()`.  `WSAStartup()` does not use `TCHAR`, only `char`, which is why there are no separate `WSAStartupA()` and `WSAStartupW()` functions for it.

If your JNA code is not able to get `WSAEnumProtocols()` and `WSAGetLastError()` working correctly, its likely that you are are declaring/using them wrong, but you did not show any of that code, so nobody can say for sure why it is not working for you.

**Update:** try something like this (I don't use JNA, so this may need some tweaking, but this will give you the general idea):

```
public interface Ws2_32 extends Library {

    // I don't know how to declare fixed size arrays in JNA,
    // so you will have to adjust these Structue declarations
    // as needed...

    public static class WSAData extends Structure {
        short wVersion;
        short wHighVersion;
        byte  szDescription[257];
        byte  szSystemStatus[129];
        short iMaxSockets;
        short iMaxUdpDg;
        String lpVendorInfo;
    };

    public static class WSAPROTOCOLCHAIN extends Structure {
        int ChainLen;
        int ChainEntries[7];
    };

    public static class WSAPROTOCOL_INFOW extends Structure {
        int dwServiceFlags1;
        int dwServiceFlags2;
        int dwServiceFlags3;
        int dwServiceFlags4;
        int dwProviderFlags;
        GUID ProviderId;
        int dwCatalogEntryId;
        WSAPROTOCOLCHAIN ProtocolChain;
        int iVersion;
        int iAddressFamily;
        int iMaxSockAddr;
        int iMinSockAddr;
        int iSocketType;
        int iProtocol;
        int iProtocolMaxOffset;
        int iNetworkByteOrder;
        int iSecurityScheme;
        int dwMessageSize;
        int dwProviderReserved;
        char szProtocol[256];
    };

    Ws2_32 INSTANCE = (Ws2_32) Native.loadLibrary("ws2_32", Ws2_32.class);

    int WSAStartup(short version, WSADATA lpwsaData);
    int WSAEnumProtocolsW(int[] lpiProtocols, WSAPROTOCOL_INFOW[] lpProtocolBuffer, IntByReference lpdwBufferLength);
    int WSACleanup();
    int WSAGetLastError();
    int WSASetLastError(int iError);
}
```

.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    WSADATA     wsaData = new WSADATA();
    short       version = 2;
    int         result = Ws2_32.INSTANCE.WSAStartup(version, wsaData);

    System.out.println("WSAStartup() returned: " + result);

    if(result == 0){
        System.out.println("WSADATA struct:");
        System.out.println("wVersion: " + wsaData.wVersion);
        System.out.println("wHighVersion: " + wsaData.wHighVersion);

        System.out.print("szDescription: ");
        for(byte b : wsaData.szDescription){
            System.out.print((char) b);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");

        System.out.print("szSystemStatus: ");
        for(byte b : wsaData.szSystemStatus){
            System.out.print((char) b);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");

        System.out.println("iMaxSockets: " + wsaData.iMaxSockets);
        System.out.println("iMaxUdpDg: " + wsaData.iMaxUdpDg");
    }
}
```

.

```
public class TestWSAEnumProtocolsA {

    public void start(){

        WSAPROTOCOL_INFOW[]     wsaprotocol_info = new WSAPROTOCOL_INFOW[1];
        WSADATA                 wsaData = new WSADATA();
        IntByReference          dwBufferLength = new IntByReference(628); // sizeof WSAPROTOCOL_INFOW, in bytes
        int                     result = 0;
        short                   version = 2;

        if((result = Ws2_32.INSTANCE.WSAStartup(version, wsaData)) != 0){
            System.out.println("Error #" + result + " at WSAStartup()");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("WSAStartup() finished correctly.");

        if((result = Ws2_32.INSTANCE.WSAEnumProtocolsW(null, wsaprotocol_info, dwBufferLength)) == -1){
            System.out.println("WSAEnumProtocolsW() returned: " + result);
            System.out.println("dwBufferLength is: " + dwBufferLength.getValue());
            System.out.println("WSAGetLastError() returned: " + Ws2_32.INSTANCE.WSAGetLastError());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and the clarification on the difference between ansi and unicode Perhaps I didn't explained myself well in the first post, but I'm calling WSAStartup() only one time at the beginning of the code and when it doesn't return an error then I call WSAEnumProtocolsW(). I've updated the question and added the code you asked. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @H3rnst: in the `main()` that you showed, you are calling `WSAStatup()` twice: `int result = Ws2_32.INSTANCE.WSAStartup(version,lpwsaData); ... if((resultado = Ws2_32.INSTANCE.WSAStartup(version,lpwsaData)) == 0){`. Change the `if` statement to `if (result == 0)` instead.

Comment: @H3rnst: you did not show your declaration of `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO`.  Since you are calling `WSAEnumProtocolsW()`, make sure the members of your `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` match WinSock's Unicode `WSAPROTOCOL_INFOW` struct.

Comment: @H3rnst: BTW, `LPWSADATA` is a pointer to a `WSADATA` struct. You need to allocate an actual `WSADATA` and pass it to `WSAStartup()` to fill in. It looks like you are only allocating a pointer, but not pointing it anywhere. Similar with `WSAEnumProtocolsW()`, you are only allocating one `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` instance, but you are setting the `lpdwBufferLength` to `-2` instead of the actual byte size of that one `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` instance. If there are multiple protocols installed, you need to allocate space for more than one `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO`.

Comment: You are right, I see it now. But that piece of code is just a test I made to make sure I had the structs right and that I was getting a valid and correct response from WSAStartup(). After running it I got the output I posted first, and then I used some of that code in the class "TestWSAEnumProtocolsA" (which I posted in the update) (disregard the name, I didn't change it but I'm calling WSAEnumProtocolsW() inside). I posted the output I got when running that class that shows that WSAGetLastError() and WSAEnumProtocolsW() aren't working.

Comment: @H3rnst: It's starting to look like you are misunderstanding how to use buffers with WinSock.

Comment: @H3rnst: when you post code on SO for reviw, please post **all relevant** code, including declarations for variables and types used by the code.

Comment: Acording to MSDN, about **lpdwBufferLength**: `On input, number of bytes in the lpProtocolBuffer buffer passed to WSAEnumProtocols. On output, the minimum buffer size that can be passed to WSAEnumProtocols to retrieve all the requested information.` That's why I call WSAEnumProtocols() with a lpdwBufferLength value of -2. If it worked properly, then it should set the value of lpdwBufferLength to the minimum size of the buffer required. That's why I output it's value before calling WSAGetLastError(). Sorry about the relevant code, I'm posting it right now.

Comment: I didn't tag you in my responses, but I already udpated the question with the code. Thank you!

Comment: @H3rnst: I added some examples to my answer.

Comment: @H3rnst: `-2` is not a valid buffer size for `lpdwBufferLength` on input. But the real reason why it is not being changed on output is because you are passing your `lpdwBufferLength` variable by value to `WSAEnumProtocol()` when you need to pass it by reference instead.

Comment: So simple yet so painfuly hard to find. Replaced int with IntByReference and WSAEnumProtocolsW() modifies the lpdwBufferLength with the right value. Now I'm getting an EXCEPTION ACCESS VIOLATION but that's probably some bug in the code I'm still trying to figure out how it works. Thank you for your patience and time.